# Is it possible to install F# on Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-xp, winforms

For my "Interface Programming" exam at the university I must bring a project in F# with Windows Forms (it's mandatory, I can't use another framework or language). The problem is that I have a Mac. I already tried running F# and Windows Forms with Mono, but it doesn't work well (or at all). I also tried to partition the hard drive and install Windows, but I ran into some problems and cannot partition the drive.

My Mac is not powerful enough to run Windows 10 inside a virtual machine, so I was wondering if it is possible to run F# and Windows Forms on Windows XP inside a VM.

If you have other suggestions I'm all ears.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but what mac do you have?  I run Windows 10 on 2006 Macbook Pro and it works fine.  Perhaps you should consider persevering with the Boot Camp option and open a separate question if you are having partitioning issues.

Comment: I don't know but A) There is a visual studio for Mac  B) you can look into what visual studio runs in XP and if that visual studio supports F# C) You can ask your parents to get you a really cheap laptop that can run wndows 7.. you should be able to find one for $150 or less.   $150 is nothnig compared to college fees so i'm sure they'll be ok with that. And it's a bit of a one off payment not like loads of $40 books every semester.

Comment: a macbook is a nice bonus, but you'll struggle donig a computing course iif you don't have a windows computer!

Comment: @barlop college fees are 300€

Comment: @GerardoZinno That's cheap but that's still a semester I guess, and a laptop with windows 7 will last  years.  And a budget laptop with windows 7 will still not be much money for anybody that is working. Seems worth it for college(which is worth a lot even if you don't pay a lot!)

Comment: Current Visual Studio Code versions require at least Windows 7. However, it seems that older versions also supported Windows XP. I found
[Visual Studio Code version 1.14.2](https://www.freesoftwarefiles.com/development/visual-studio-code-1-14-2-free-download/), which the documentation claims runs in Windows XP. Unfortunately, I cannot test this claim.

Comment: mono does not support windows forms, it only winforms only works on windows.  you have to use GTK, QT or or Avalalon

Answer (score 0):

Run Ubuntu 18.04 from a virtual machine or from a live USB by following the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287064/how-do-i-make-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb/451866#451866). Then open the terminal and install the F# compiler using the following command:

```
sudo apt install fsharp mono-complete
sudo snap install monowinformsspy
```

The fsharp package contains an F# compiler targeting the CLI runtime.

Visual Studio Code is a full-featured code editor that has F# support via a choice of several F# extensions in the Visual Studio Code Extensions Marketplace. To install Visual Studio Code open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install vscode --classic
```

Once you start programming on the Ubuntu platform you'll probably use it again and again, because Ubuntu is a versatile OS and many programming language compilers and other programming packages can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories.

*For WinForms you will need to install MonoDevelop*<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397605/)</sup> from the [official MonoDevelop website](https://www.monodevelop.com/download/). MonoDevelop is a cross platform IDE for C#, F# and more.

In Ubuntu 18.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https dirmngr
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu vs-bionic main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-vs.list
sudo apt update
```

Comment: You'll have a bad time trying to use winforms with Visual Studio Code.